# Allow simple if statement without else to have no braces in codestyle

Tags: java, if-statement, checkstyle

I use [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) to check if my java code respects the guidelines of our project.

However, we have one guideline that I cannot figure out how to check with this tool. We want to allow simple if (understand if with no else and no other conditional structure in it) to have no brace, like in this example :

```
// valid
if(condition) callFunction();

// invalid
if(condition) for(int i = 0; i < someValue; i++) callFunction(i);

// valid
if(condition) {
    for(int i = 0; i < someValue; i++) {
        callFunction(i);
    }
}

// invalid
if(condition) callFunction();
else callOtherFunction();
```

This convention can be discussed, but this is the one we chose. It allows a reduced if syntax for very trivial cases, but ensures we have good indentation and block delimitation for more complex structures.

Any help with that would be really appreciated.

I'm also ready to do some code to perform this check if nothing is available, but really don't know where to start. In last ressort, some tips about that will be appreciated too.

Comment: My serious suggestion is to change your guidelines. You're spending time looking for a solution to make your style guidelines *inferior*.  Inline if statements like this (that don't use blocks) lead to bugs.  Really, really nasty bugs.

Comment: @Mark I don't know about using inline ifs for simple function calls, but I think it's reasonable to use them to check some conditions and throw an exception if the conditions aren't met.

Comment: This question isn't about whether the guidelines are reasonable.  This question is about how to modify checkstyle to support these guidelines.  I think we should avoid discussing the guidelines themselves in this question.

Comment: @Erick: You could say that about a large percentage of the questions on this site.  My end goal is to help people.  If that means questioning requirements and thus negating the need for a technical answer, so be it.  Many things are hard to do because they *should* be hard to do.  Notice that I didn't say this was an *answer*.

Comment: @Mark Android coding guidelines allow for it, It's purley a matter of opinion: http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html#use-standard-brace-style

Comment: @Bengt: I don't think it's purely a matter of opinion when I've seen bad bugs due to this style choice.  BTW, the guidelines you cite only allow it when the consequence occurs without a line break.  Personally I feel that goes a ways to lessoning the harmful effects of allowing a no-brace if statement.  The OP didn't mention the same limitation.

Comment: @Mark Okey, I interpreted the question in the wrong way then. Personally I always go for braces.

Comment: @Mark, can you point me some documentation about the problems you faced with if with no braces repecting the following guidelines ?

Comment: @deadalnix: My aversion comes from experience not documentation.  A couple of weeks ago I came across code in a legacy product where the non-block `if`was used (as a null guard) and then subsequent statements were indented as if they were part of the block.  Only the first statement was actually guarded by the null check and if someone ever actually passed in null the method would have thrown up.

Comment: We have rules about identation to prevent that (I faced similar problems in the past). And we want non blicks if to be on one line. But both are matter of others formating rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end, I did implement a custom check for checkstyle. Here is the source code if someone else is interested in it :

```
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.Check;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.DetailAST;
import com.puppycrawl.tools.checkstyle.api.TokenTypes;

public class IfBracesCheck extends Check {

    @Override
    public int[] getDefaultTokens() {
        return new int[] {
            TokenTypes.LITERAL_ELSE,
            TokenTypes.LITERAL_IF,
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void visitToken(DetailAST aAST) {
        final DetailAST slistAST = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.SLIST);

        if(aAST.getType() == TokenTypes.LITERAL_ELSE) {
            // If we have an else, it must have braces, except it is an "else if" (then the if must have braces).
            DetailAST ifToken = aAST.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.LITERAL_IF);

            if(ifToken == null) {
                // This is an simple else, it must have brace.
                if(slistAST == null) {
                    log(aAST.getLineNo(), "ifBracesElse", aAST.getText());
                }
            } else {
                // This is an "else if", the if must have braces.
                if(ifToken.findFirstToken(TokenTypes.SLIST) == null) {
                    log(aAST.getLineNo(), "ifBracesConditional", ifToken.getText(), aAST.getText() + " " + ifToken.getText());
                }
            }
        } else if(aAST.getType() == TokenTypes.LITERAL_IF) {
            // If the if uses braces, nothing as to be checked.
            if (slistAST != null) {
                return;
            }

            // We have an if, we need to check if it has no conditionnal structure as direct child.
            final int[] conditionals = {
                TokenTypes.LITERAL_DO,
                TokenTypes.LITERAL_ELSE,
                TokenTypes.LITERAL_FOR,
                TokenTypes.LITERAL_IF,
                TokenTypes.LITERAL_WHILE,
                TokenTypes.LITERAL_SWITCH,
            };

            for(int conditional : conditionals) {
                DetailAST conditionalAST = aAST.findFirstToken(conditional);

                if (conditionalAST != null) {
                    log(aAST.getLineNo(), "ifBracesConditional", aAST.getText(), conditionalAST.getText());

                    // Let's trigger this only once.
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add that now checkstyle supports 'allowSingleLineIf' property which covers some cases.

```
    <module name="NeedBraces">
        <property name="allowSingleLineIf" value="true"/>
    </module>
```

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with the comments that this is a bad idea, you might not be able to change the guidelines. So you might want to try this:

1. In the checkstyle module *Blocks* -> *Need braces*, disable the *if* keyword
2. Create a new instance of the module *Regexp* -> *RegexpSingleLineJava* and try to find a regexp that matches your invalid cases but not your valid ones

(Module names are from Eclipse Checkstyle Plugin 5.3.0)

Comment: I thought at something like that, but regex isn't powerfull enough to handle that rule, even it is probably a part of the solution.

Comment: Regexp is pretty powerful ;) From your examples, the second example is already invalid, as long as the for-statement is required to have braces. The forth example is still valid, but I have an regexp that is working - just not in checkstyle. Maybe you can figure it out: (?s)if.*;.*else

Comment: No, this doesn't do the trick : ensure that no conditionnal structure exists within the if is almost impossible using regex, and the variety of cases require some logic. Your proposal will match a very large variety of cases, including legal use of if. Anyway, I guess that with some regex and a bit of logic, something can be managed here.

Answer (score 0):

CheckStyle 6.14 NeedBracesCheck rool support *allowSingleLineStatement* option

> allowSingleLineStatement which allows single-line statements without braces, e.g.:
>
> if (obj.isValid()) return true;
>
> while (obj.isValid()) return true;
>
> do this.notify(); while (o != null);
>
> for (int i = 0; ; ) this.notify();

[documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/blocks/NeedBracesCheck.html)